# How to access Django message framework content in Django unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-middleware

Using the Django messages framework, I am passing messages to the template to render in various scenarios - user account creation successful etc. The message is stored within the cookie for the session:

```
print response.cookies['messages']
Set-Cookie: messages="b6870b4797b65640bb535519a5b53808fdc0ea24$[[\"__json_message\"\05420\054\"Account verified\054 you are now logged in\"]]"; Path=/
```

The cookie is a [Morsel](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#morsel-objects) object, but I don't appear to be able to pull out the constituent parts of it to test the message content. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit: 10-05-2014:**

An alternative method is to iterate the messages in the response context. Using the Django Test Client, the response message items can be parsed via:

```
for message in response.context['messages']:
```

Which returns each Django [Message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#the-message-class) object, you can then interrogate the attributes for your tests. This is a cleaner alternative to the original option.

**Original Solution:**

For archive purposes, the original working solution was to interrogate the Cookie morsel objects in the response cookies. This is less clean than the new solution.

```
self.assertTrue('Account verified' in response.cookies['messages'].value)
```

in the unittest. It seems quite an ugly solution, but since there won't be another 'Account verified' set, nor another simultaneous message, then it seems acceptable.

Comment: looks like the `response.text` solution won't work if the view returns a redirect tho.  thanks for the `response.cookies` solution tho!  I wonder if I can figure out how to turn them back into proper message objects...

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for: `response.cookies['messages'].value`